# video control display size should be of the vertical Field manager in blackberry

Tags: blackberry-storm

i am new to blackberry
recently i am working on a camera application 
in which in the method initialize camera 
i am using the videocontrol object to initialize the camera
and the code which i used is as follows:
 private void initializeCamera()
        {

```
      try
        {
            // Create a player for the Blackberry's camera
            Player player = Manager.createPlayer( "capture://video" );
            // Set the player to the REALIZED state (see Player javadoc)
            player.realize();
            _videoControl = (VideoControl)player.getControl( "VideoControl" );

            if (_videoControl != null)
            {

                _videoField = (Field) _videoControl.initDisplayMode (VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE,"net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");

                _videoControl.setDisplaySize(460,320 );

                _videoControl.setVisible(true);


            }
         player.start();




        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Camera.errorDialog("ERROR " + e.getClass() + ":  " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

on implementing such a code i got an image of the default video control size
but i want that the controller should occupy the enitre size of the 
vertical field manager

even on using the code:
    "_videoControl.setDisplaySize(460,320 );"
the controller is not able to occupy the size as shown

so can anybody help me in this regard

regards
Pinkesh Gupta

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the flags `MainScreen.USE_ALL_WIDTH|MainScreen.USE_ALL_HEIGHT` in your main screen constructor.
Check out [what blackberry says about this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/java_dev@tkb/article-id/458)